# Number of samples for doing FFT

Tags: fft, sample

I have a set of 10006 samples which resembles 10 period s of a 50 hz signal which is sampled with 50 KHZ.

as you know the freqeuncy of bins are calculated via SF/N where SF is sampling frequency and N is the number of samples.

I want to have the magnitudes of the frequency in integer multiples of 5 HZ up to 9 KHZ  (for example: 5 , 10 , ..., 1025, 1030...,8000, 80005..9000).

so if I do the fft with 10006 samples my frequency bins are not any more the integer multiples of 5 and instead they are integer multiples of 50000/10006. 
and if I truncate my samples then i will have integer multiples of 5 Hz bins but my samples are not any more resembling exactly 10 periods which means I have leakge effec !

so I am wondering how to have exactlu 5 HZ bins and with out having the spectrum distorted by leakage effect ?!!

Comment: you need to read about the principles of FFT and you should never truncate your data

Comment: thanks for your hint but what am I supposed to read exactly in details, to get the knowlege about this issue ?

Comment: just grab Digital Signal Processing by Oppenheim

Comment: Why did you decide to sample a 50Hz signal at 50KHz? Nyquist theory states that using just twice the highest frequency will preserve your data so you didn't need to sample your signal with a sampling frequency that high.

Answer (score 0):

You can truncate and then window to reduce "leakage" effects.  Or zero-pad to 20k points without windowing and resample the FFT result.